# ComponentDidCatch does not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Why `componentDidCatch` does not work in my react-native app.
`componentDidCatch` does not handle errors.

```
React native v: 50.3
React: 16.0.0
```

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text}        from 'react-native';
import Logo               from './SignUpInit/Logo';
import SignUp             from './SignUpInit/SignUp';
import Social             from './SignUpInit/Social';
import styles             from './SignUpInit/styles';

export default class SignUpInit extends Component {

    state = {
        componentCrashed: false,
        count: 0,
    }

    componentDidCatch(error, info) {
        console.log(error);
        console.log(info);
        console.log('_______DID CATCH____________');
        this.setState({componentCrashed: true});
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        setInterval(()=>this.setState({count: this.state.count+1}),1000);
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.componentCrashed) {
            return (
                <View>
                    <Text>
                        Error in component "SingUpInit"
                    </Text>
                </View>
            );
        }

        if(this.state.count > 5){
            throw new Error('Error error error');
        }


        return (
            <View style={styles.main}>
                <Logo/>
                <SignUp/>
                <Social/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You're going to need to provide more detail than that if you want other people to help. Post the code here, with a reproducable example if possible

Comment: You're going to need to provide more detail. What doesn't work? What do you expect to happen? Can you provide relevant code or a working example?

Comment: You're going to need to provide more detail. Post your component, what exactly doesn't work? How do you tell?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This doesn't work because `componentDidCatch()` only works for catching errors thrown by a components children. Here it seems like you are trying to catch an error thrown by the same component - that's not going to work.

See the [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/07/26/error-handling-in-react-16.html#introducing-error-boundaries) for more info:

> Error boundaries are React components that **catch JavaScript errors anywhere in their child component tree, log those errors, and display a fallback UI** instead of the component tree that crashed.

Note the *"anywhere in their child component tree"*.

---

So all you need to do is to wrap your component inside another component that manages all errors thrown. Something like:

```
<ErrorBoundary>
  <SignUpInit />
</ErrorBoundary>
```

Where `<ErrorBoundary />` is something as simple as:

```
class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {hasError: false};
  }

  componentDidCatch(error, info) {
    this.setState({hasError: true});
  }

  render() {
    if(this.state.hasError) return <div>Error!</div>;
    return this.props.children;
  }
}
```