# Can we catch the exception raised from action by using componentDidCatch in our component?

Tags: reactjs

I am migrating code to `React v16.0` I have a confusion that can I use `componentDidCatch` to catch the error thrown by the action call. First let me clarify that this question is not a duplicate of [componentDidCatchNotWorking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47223765/componentdidcatch-does-not-work?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

My action call is like this:

```
export default {
 getEmployeeList() {
  return function (dispatch) {
    commonApi.getEmployeeList()
     .then((response) => {
       }).catch((reasonObj: any) => {
                   throw new Error('Error');
       });
      };
    }
```

Now In My Component I am calling this action:

```
componentWillMount() {
  this.props.actions.getEmployeeList();
}
```

Render Code for the EmployeeList component is:

```
render(){
   return (
    <div className="container">
     <ErrorBoundary>
     <EmployeeList/>
     </ErrorBoundary>
  )
}
```

`EmployeeList` is my component from which I am calling the action. Now my confusion is that can I catch the exception raised from action to my component with help of `componentDidCatch`. Please assist me, Is it possible or not?