# componentDidCatch - a void element tag

Tags: reactjs

The code presented below causes an error "input is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`". With Comp1 it's properly caught by componentDidUpdate, but when I change it to Comp2 the app just crashes. Why is that?

```
const Comp1 = () => <input>ABC</input>
const Comp2 = () => <input><div /></input>

class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  state = { error: '' };
  componentDidCatch(error) {
    this.setState({ error: error.toString() });
  }
  render() {
    return this.state.error ? <div>ERROR: {this.state.error}</div> : <Comp1 />
  }
}
```

It seems that in 16.4.2 it worked for both cases.

Comment: You should not nest component inside `input`. As it is invalid input usage. Please use either `<input/>` or replace `input` with some other component.

Comment: I want to create components from code entered by user and I need to detect when it's incorrect.

Comment: And what happens when you use some other components instead of `<input/>` ?

Comment: I dont' have that problem. With your code I was able to catch both Comp1 and Comp2 in your ErrorBoundary component

Comment: In 16.5.2 it doesn't work: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LgxGOo  (it worked with 16.4.2).

Comment: It shouldn't work in any version. React Error Boundaries can't catch errors thrown from children, not the component itself

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47223765/componentdidcatch-does-not-work/47224258#47224258

Comment: So wthat's the difference between Comp1 and Comp2, that this is working only for the former?

Comment: Comp2 is a child od ErrorBoundary. So ErrorBoundary should catch an error "anywhere in their child component tree". If I'm doing it wrong, what is the right way?

Comment: Must be tired. I could've sworn I saw the error in the main component. Sorry, I misread.